# Visual Studio Team Services Build Definition - How to Copy sources folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

I’m trying to create a build definition in Visual Studio 2013 using TfvcTemplate.12.xaml as template. One of my objectives is to copy the sources folder to the drop folder. 
I already tried to use CopyDirectory method, but without success. 
How can I copy the sources folder of my solution to the drop folder?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the post-test PowerShell call to add a PowerShell script to your build that is called after tests have run.

You can call a "move-item" ps command to move the bits and you can access both the source and binaries location from the environmental variables.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh850448.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn376353.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual Studio online you can add (or edit) a Step called "Copy Files" to your build definition and add "***" to the "Content" field, it will include everything on the drop archive. Bear in mind that this might make your build process a lot slower (depending on the steps you have).

I'm not sure how easy it would be to replicate this behaviour using the Xaml templates but I assume it should be straight forward as well.